# Error when I add another table to FROM in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

This is a working query

```
SELECT
     DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') as Date_and_Time
FROM
    dbo.V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG
WHERE
    EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'
    and EVENT_DESC LIKE '%Downloaded%'
    and TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  * CAST(1000 as bigint)
```

When I want to query more information, i.e. getting the computer name by adding another column to SELECT, another table to FROM and another boolean statement to WHERE

```
SELECT
    dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_NAME, DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') as Date_and_Time
FROM
    dbo.V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG, dbo.sem_computer
WHERE
    EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'
    and EVENT_DESC LIKE '%Downloaded%'
    and TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  * CAST(1000 as bigint)
    and dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG.COMPUTER_ID
```

I get the following error

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'TIME_STAMP'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'TIME_STAMP'.
```

Why is there an error with TIME_STAMP just because I am querying more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common effect when writing queries with column names that aren't qualified (= referenced to the table).

With a single table it's usually not required, but as soon as there's another table added to the query there's a chance of duplicate column names where SQL Server cannot identify the table to select the values from.

My guess: your table dbo.sem_computerdoes also contain a column named TIME_STAMP.

If so, you'll need to add the table name (or even better, an alias) to the columns to identify the source table.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you have a TIME_STAMP field in your V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG table and in your sem_computer table.  SQL doesn't know which field you want to refer to with

```
DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') as Date_and_Time
```

and

```
and TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  * CAST(1000 as bigint)
```

If you qualify all fields in the query like this, you won't run into this issue:

```
SELECT
    sc.COMPUTER_NAME, DATEADD(SECOND, asl.TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') as Date_and_Time
FROM
    dbo.V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG asl, dbo.sem_computer sc
WHERE
    asl.EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'
    and asl.EVENT_DESC LIKE '%Downloaded%'
    and asl.TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  * CAST(1000 as bigint)
    and sc.COMPUTER_ID = asl.COMPUTER_ID
```

Note: I guessed on your field sources, you need to qualify it based on your own table structure.